# mysql_num_rows($query) > 0 dosen't work

Tags: php

I am trying to know if there is an existing data in the database, we I try to use existing username, based on my coding it should be "exists already", but the result is "proceed". Can you point out where I am wrong?

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `membership` WHERE `username` = '$username'");
if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){  
    echo "exists already";
}
else {
    echo "proceed";
}
```

Comment: Can you add an `if (!$query) { die(mysql_error()); }` after your `$query = ...` ? - Besides that: 1) The mysql_*-functions are deprecated, consider using mysqli_* or PDO. 2) Learn about mysql-injection.

Comment: thx, I tried mysqli, it works.

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
$str = "select  SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * from table where username=".$your_value;

$con=db_connect();

$result1        =   mysql_query($str,$con);
$str1           =   "SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as totalRecord";

$result2        =   mysql_query($str1,$con);

$totalRecords   =   mysql_fetch_array($result2);



if ($totalRecords[0]>0){

echo "exists already";
}  
else{echo "proceed";}
```

also try using **mysqli or pdo** as mysql is depricated...